# changing a character to a different character in a text field

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to make a de coding type of app, where you have a code "a=z, b=y, c=x" and when a user puts a jumble of letters in the text field it will de-code it for them. For example.  I put in "a b c" and when I click a button it will display in another text field "z y x".

I have tried using Regex like this:

```
NSString *inputFieldContents = inputField.text; // Suppose it's "Hello, zyxw!";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"zyxw" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];

NSRange range = NSMakeRange (0, [inputFieldContents length]);
NSString *res = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:inputFieldContents options:0 range:range withTemplate:@"abcd"];
NSLog(@"%@", res);
```

But this will only give me the decoded message if the letters zyxw are inputed.  If I enter wxyz, it won't give me dcba like I would like it to.

Does anybody have any ideas of how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm no regex master, but I believe you'll just have to do three separate replacements. I don't think you can do something like this with Cocoa's regular expressions.

Comment: Actually, scratch that, I think that's what "capture groups" are for. You might want to look into those in the documentation.

Comment: And... nevermind again. Those still can only match one pattern at a time. You'll need to use multiple replaces either way.

Comment: I did the multiple replaces but have no way to combine all of the replaces into one.  I can't find a way to make all the replaces and display one string with all the replacements on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could simply replace strings within a mutable string using:

`-[NSMutableString replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:]`.

and if your case is very basic, you may favor:

`-[NSString  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]`

---

Update - so one way to approach this would be:

```
NSMutableString * str = [inputField.text mutableCopy];

enum { NumSubstitutions = 4 };
NSString * const sought[NumSubstitutions] = { @"z", @"y", @"x", @"w" };
NSString * const replacements[NumSubstitutions] = { @"a", @"b", @"c", @"d" };

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < NumSubstitutions; ++i) {
    [str replaceOccurrencesOfString:sought[i]
                         withString:replacements[i]
                            options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
                              range:NSMakeRange(0, inputFieldContents.length)];
}

return [str copy];
```

Comment: To expand on this (correct answer), you run this for each of your replacements, ..ofString:@"z" withString:"a"

Comment: @DavidH thanks -- i've added an example of how one would go about swapping using these methods.